# Compare 2 dataframes imported from excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am working on data comparison project. Here i have 2 excel files 'Prod1' and 'Proj1' which i had imported in python as data frames. Both the data frames have 46 identical columns with identical labels. But different number of rows across both files (e.g. Prod1 is having 100 while Proj1 is 110). I want to compare cell by cell values and highlight the mismatch as 'TRUE' or 'FALSE'in another dataframe. Which can be further exported in excel. Till now i am able to read the files but got struck in comparison part. Kindly assist

```
import os

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import xlrd

os.getcwd()

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\desktop\\Python Project")

Prod1= pd.read_excel("Prod1.xls")

df1 = pd.read_excel('Prod1.xls', 'Prod1')

print(df1)

df2 = pd.read_excel('Proj1.xls', 'Proj1')

print(df2)
```

Comment: Show us how print(df1.head()) looks like. Also tell us the format you want the exported excel in

Comment: print(df1.head(0))
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ACCT_DIM_ID, SEC_DIM_ID, POS_TYPE_DIM_ID, DAY_DIM_ID, COMPOSITE_KEY, PSI_FACTSET, ACCT_NUM, TRANSACTION_NUM, TIS_SEQ, ORIGINAL_FACE, QUANTITY, TRADE_DATE, SETTLEMENT_DATE, TRADE_PRICE_LOCAL, ACCRUED_INTEREST_LOCAL, NET_AMOUNT_LOCAL, TRANSACTION_CD, LOCAL_CURRENCY, BASE_CURRENCY, TIS_TRADE_NUM, FX_CONTRACT_AMT, FX_CONTRACT_CURRENCY, PRINCIPAL_AMT, PRINCIPAL_AMT_BASE, TAX_DATE, ENTRY_DATE, ENTRY_TIME, REVERSAL_DATE, REVERSAL_TIME, THROUGH_DATE, CASH_DECREASE_LOCAL, CASH_INCREASE_LOCAL, TRANSACTION_TYPE, QUANTITY_ADDED, QUANTITY_REMOVED,

Comment: Ok you got lots of columns. Try to share data with df1.head(1) at least.

Comment: Output should be in excel format. I wasn't able to add all the columns due to   character constraints. File is a columns are a mix of strings,number,, dates.

Comment: print(df1.head(1))
   ACCT_DIM_ID  SEC_DIM_ID  POS_TYPE_DIM_ID DAY_DIM_ID  \
0          443      599133               86 2018-02-01   

                           COMPOSITE_KEY   PSI_FACTSET  ACCT_NUM  \
0  638806--P-USD-38848-20180201-134904--  X9X9USDBLKR9       515   

   TRANSACTION_NUM   TIS_SEQ  ORIGINAL_FACE        ...          \
0            38848  638806.0              0        ...           

   SYSTEM_LAST_UPDATED_BY_USER_ID SYSTEM_LAST_UPDATED_DATE  \
0                             PMA      2018-02-01 23:30:16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming df2 is the larger dataframe, as you say in your explanation, resize to match df1:

```
>>> df1 = df1.reindex(index=df2.index)
```

Then just print the following:

```
>>> print(df1 == df2)
```

**Example**

```
# Define two Pandas Dataframes

>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1,2], 'col2': [3,4]})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1,2,3], 'col2': [3,4,5]})

>>> df1
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4

>>> df2
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
2     3     5
```

The Dataframes purposely don't match in size, so if you tried to do the following:

```
>>> print(df1 == df2)
```

You would see an error like this:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects
```

In order to compare the two, use the index of the bigger Dataframe df2 (this describes the labels applied to each row) and we use it to redefine the index of df1. Note this only works if the two datasets utilise the same indexing.

```
>>> df1 = df1.reindex(index=df2.index)
>>> df1
   col1  col2
0   1.0   3.0
1   2.0   4.0
2   NaN   NaN
```

Now if you try to compare them, you will see the following:

```
>>> print(df1 == df2)
    col1   col2
0   True   True
1   True   True
2  False  False
```

Comment: Hi Ben, could you please explain the code just for understanding df1 = df1.reindex(index=df2.index)

Comment: @AbhishekGupta Basically you give df1 the same index as df2 (df2 has a longer index and thus df1 is filled with nans in the end).

Comment: Hey @AbhishekGupta, I'll some add more detail to the answer and show an example.

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach you want to have, first let's recreate two dataframes:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(2,2)),columns=list('AB'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(4,2)),columns=list('AB'))
```

Df1,  Df2:

```
   A  B       A  B
0  1  1    0  0  0       # False
1  0  1    1  0  1       # True
           2  1  1       # False
           3  1  1       # False
```

Now we compare those dataframes row-wise by zipping the values together and make sure all `.all()` values are the same.

```
[(a==b).all() for a,b in itertools.zip_longest(df1.values, df2.values)]
```

Or without izip_longest:

```
[(a==b).all() for a,b in zip(df1.values, df2.values)]+[False]*abs(len(df2)-len(df1))
```

And output is:

```
[False, True, False, False]
```